# Java Dedicated GPU on Fullscreen not working after the update on the 25th of April

Tags: graphics-card, java, gpu, fullscreen

I have a Dell E5440 with a dedicated Nvidia GPU. I used to play Minecraft on an external monitor with no problem till Java got an update a few days ago.

Since the last Java update, when I switch the game to Fullscreen, Java decides to use the Integrated Intel GPU. I tried to force Java to use the dedicated GPU from both Nvidia Control Panel and Graphics Settings on Windows Control Panel.

Now bare in mind, I am an Electronics Engineer so I quite know things about computers and at this point, I consider I tried everything that's possible on my end to make it work. Even set custom settings for Java individual exe files to use the Dedicated GPU with no success.

Prior to the Java update, everything was working fine. Nothing changed with the hardware. Not even wiring.
Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: Have you tried to revert to the previous version of Java?

Comment: @Ramhound I am in the process of reinstalling Java right now. If it doesn't work. Will try that.

Comment: @Ramhound Same problem on JRE 8 291 and 281. Will try older versions as I know it has been some time since I last updated it.

Comment: Your issue obviously isn’t the Java 8 update since it was released over a week ago and installing the previous version didn’t work, the only possible reason, is due to TLS 1.0 and 1.1 being disabled by default but a current version of Minecraft wouldn’t have a problem

Comment: Also check Windows update history on the day things changed, and see if rollback fixes the issue.

Comment: @DuncG I don't know the day when things changed as I have not played the game in like two weeks. The only thing I noticed was the Java update notification and I did the update then decided to play as it reminded me of the game. I tried and it didn't work.